# cannot get var value from model.ts file?

Tags: angular, angular-module

1. I create a file home.model.ts in that 
   `class  FormDataModel {
   leadId: string;
   roofArea: number;`
   }

2.import in the home.component.ts also do 
model = new FormDataModel()
when i fetch leadId and console to check it give undefine
// i try like this
console.log(this.model.leadId)

Answer (score 1):

You could send in the values using constructor in the model. Try the following

form-data-model.ts

```js
export class FormData {
  constructor(
    private _leadId: string,
    private _roofArea: number,
  ) { }

  get leadId() { return this._leadId };
  set leadId(id: string) { this._leadId = id };

  get roofArea() { return this._roofArea };
  set roofArea(area: number) { this._roofArea = area };
}
```

Component

```js
import { FormData } from './form-data-model';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  formData: FormData = new FormData('sample_id', 1000);

  consturctor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.formData);
  }
}
```

Working example: [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8runju)

Comment: model = new FormDataModel('sample_id', 1000);  i try this but show error that only 0 arg it take

Comment: I've updated the model with private values, getter/setters and include a working demo. Please check if it works for you.